# SQL incremental data

Tags: sql, reporting-services

i am trying to get only incremental records on one of the table SQL.

Example Table1--need to insert data 10 times per day from some source data. Suppose I have inserted 10 records in the morning. Another new records came after one hour. SO total will be 20 records. And it keep going more and more through all day. And I need to run script to show only increment part. SO whatever I show in the morning should not include next run. Basically each time main table updated , i need to run script to show only updated new rows not old exiting rows.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Add a batch number to to the data and then you can query the data only returning the latest batch. Something like this.

**During Insert**

```
DECLARE @Batch INT = (SELECT MAX(BatchNo)+1 as NextBatchNo FROM myTable)
IF @Batch IS NULL 
   SET @Batch = 1

INSERT INTO myTable (firstColumn, secondColumn, anotherColumn, BatchNo)
  SELECT firstColumn, secondColumn, anotherColumn, @Batch 
      FROM mySourceDataTable
```

**To get the latest rows inserted**

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
    WHERE Batch = (SELECT MAX(Batch) FROM myTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Query the table to display output for the last 24 days, using the Date function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have oracle database then you can use flashback feature to get this data.

Link for more details
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/flashptr002.htm